# How to replace a word in word document using python without changing the font of output?

Tags: python

I have been trying to run a script that searches for a pattern and replaces the placeholder with another word and saves it to another folder. But when the replacement is made, it also changes the font of the word document, which is what I want to avoid, while retaining the same font even after replacement.

[

```html
search_results=re.compile(r'\<.*?\>')
for file in glob.glob('./*.docx'):
    print(file)
    document = Document(file)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if search_results.search(paragraph.text):
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("<", "<#common.").replace(">","#>")
            print(paragraph.text)
    output=r'./Output'+file
    print(output)
    document.save(output)
```

][1]

Comment: That regex seems like it would match _every_ tag. Are you sure you don't want to make it a bit more specific, to affect only certain tags? It might be replacing, say, `<font>` tags with `<#common.font#>` tags, which might not mean anything in .docx. I don't know which tags are actually responsible for setting the font, but I think it's likely one of them is getting 'corrupted' in this way and MS Word no longer recognizes it.

Comment: I wanted to match all the content inside the word document specified within angular brackets, these angular brackets aren't any tags, just some special symbols that are marked within the word that needs to be replaced. But seems like on replacing the content the font of the entire paragraph seems to loose the font and switches to calibri

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SidharthMM DOCX is a fundamentally XML-based format. I think it's extremely likely that your find-and-replace is replacing things you don't actually want it to. In your debugging, have you tried looking at what `paragraph.text` looks like in the code before doing your replacement, so you can see _what_ it's replacing?